# Is there a way to disable canvas interaction?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm working in a web application that allows user to create a scene using *canvas* element, and then using Web Audio Api the scene changes accordingly with extracted frequencies in real time (creating audio visualizations). I implemented the interactivity with canvas with eventListeners.

My question here is if there is a way to disable canvas interaction (stop eventListeners) while the song is playing (the scene is changing) and after user stops it, the scene can be modified again.

Thank you all.

Comment: If the events you want to disable are mouse generated, you can temporarely add `pointer-events: none` to the canvas.

Comment: And what about if some of those events are generated by pressing DOM elements of the interface? (Like clicking buttons as "Add new shape").

Btw I'll try your solution. Thx @a.barbieri

Comment: Anything `pointer` related are covered by `pointer-events`. See [MDN documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13456810/1498118)